# Coloring pdf cell, vertical text in fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am just using `fpdf` library to generate **pdf output**,
some problems i had come across are:

1) how to change background color of a cell, i tried with `$pdf->SetFillColor(255,0,0);` but fails.

2) how to type text in **vertically** ?

the code stuff i'm using is:

```
$pdf->SetXY(10,15);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'text to display',1,0,'C',0);
```

here is the output i have to get:

[image]

Comment: Did you create an extended class ?

Comment: no, what is it..??
i am doing with codeigniter, the source files are included in config file

Comment: you should read the manual at their website

Comment: Why don't you use an online html to pdf converter with API ? It's more easy and it accept more html & css code... For fill a cell you just need to set up a background..

Take a look at:

http://simplehtmltopdf.com
http://pdfcrowd.com/
http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

Hope that helps...

Verify that the seventh parameter of Cell function is to 1 (true)...

```
...
    $pdf->SetFillColor(255,0,0);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'text to display',1,0,'C',1); 
...
```

And write vertically, until now, the best solution i found was to adjust the angle by using sine and cosine:

```
...
function Girar($angulo=0,$x=-1,$y=-1) 
{ 
    if($x==-1) $x=$this->x; 

    if($y==-1) $y=$this->y; 

    if($this->angulo!=0) $this->_out('Q'); 

    $this->angulo=$angulo; 
    if($angulo!=0) 
    { 
        $angulo*=M_PI/180; 
        $c=cos($angulo); 
        $s=sin($angulo); 
        $cx=$x*$this->k; 
        $cy=($this->h-$y)*$this->k; 

        $this->_out(sprintf('q %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.2f %.2f cm 1 0 0 1 %.2f %.2f cm',$c,$s,-$s,$c,$cx,$cy,-$cx,-$cy)); 
    } 
}
$pdf->Girar(270); $pdf->Cell(120,5,'text to display',1,1,'C');
...
```